# VSCode JQuery intellisense without Node.js?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've been trying to setup VSCode as a Javascript Environment. So far so good by just installing the ES6 snippers extension. However I can't get the JQuery auto-completion intellisense to work. I know there are a lot of guides on how to setup that, but they all require Node.js and I am not using it, so is there a way to setup the JQuery intellisense properly without Node.js?

I have tried using non-minified version of JQuery and then adding `/// <reference path="path_to_query"/` to the beginning of my .js file, but that doesn't work.

All I want to do is having the jquery auto-completion to work without Node.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [the types package for jQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery) as a [development dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file):

```
npm i -D "@types/jquery"
```

Comment: This works: npm install --save @types/jquery